# How to color only the faces where the normals are perpendicular to the camera

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl

[image]

I am trying to do the math for a shader that needs to darken on the faces that have normals perpendicular to the camera (dot product is 0). So basically how do I get this dot product?
How do I fix the following?

```c
uniform float time;
uniform vec3 eye_dir;

varying float darkening;

void main(){

  float product=dot(normalize(eye_dir),normalize(normal.xyz));

  darkening=product;

  gl_Position=
  projectionMatrix*
  modelViewMatrix*
  vec4(position,1.);
}
```

```js
// in THREE.js
this.camera.getWorldDirection(this.eyeDir);
...
cell.material.uniforms.eye_dir = new Uniform(this.eyeDir);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you want you've to calculate the vector from the fragment to the camera. The easiest way to do this, is to do it in view space (camera space), because in view space the position of the camera is (0, 0, 0).
Transform the `position` by the `modelViewMatrix` from model space to view space and the `normal` by the `normalMatrix` from model space to view space. See [WebGLProgram](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram).

Since the result of the dot product is 1.0 when the vectors are orientated in the same direction, the darkening is `1.0 - abs(dotproduct)`.

```c
varying float darkening;

void main(){

    vec4 view_pos = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

    vec3 view_dir = normalize(-view_pos.xyz); // vec3(0.0) - view_pos;
    vec3 view_nv  = normalize(normalMatrix * normal.xyz);

    float NdotV   = dot(view_dir, view_nv);
    darkening     = 1.0 - abs(NdotV);

    gl_Position   = projectionMatrix * view_pos;
}
```

Note, the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of `eye_dir` and `normal` doesn't make any sense at all, because `eye_dir` is a vector in world space and `normal` is a vector in model (object) space.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. My hurdle is the view-space vs world-space idea. Just hard to visualize.